# Reloading Variable Value when the value is updated from Server (FLASK, HTML, JQUERY)

Tags: python, jquery, flask

I am very new to python and am starting to learn about using AJAX and Jquery.
I'm going to try to formulate my problem clearly but if it's in any way unclear, please tell me so and I will try to improve it.

I have a web app which is run from the function userinterface.py, and userinterface.py should be run from the function central.py.

In central.py, there is a variable called "devicequantity", which should be assigned to a div element in the html. I tried using ajax request for this (devicequantity is a changing variable).

In my web app, there are some fields that are hidden depending on the value of devicequantity. How can I assign devicequantity to the web app and let it update whenever a new value is assigned via central.py? Thank you so much for any feedback and help!

Here are my codes:

**html**

```
<div class="col-sm-4 d-inline-flex justify-content-center align-items-center my-0">
  Device quantity:
  <div class="border col-sm-5 px-2 py-2 justify-content-center align-items-center" type="number" id="devicequantity" name="devicequantity"> {{ devicequantity }} </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url:"/getdevicequantity",
      type: "get",
      success: function(response){
        $("#devicequantity").html(response.devicequantity);
      }
    });
    $('#alertsettings').hide(); $('#alertfillfield').hide(); $("#device1").hide(); $("#device2").hide(); $("#device3").hide(); $("#device4").hide(); $("#device5").hide(); $("#device6").hide(); $("#device7").hide(); $("#device8").hide(); $("#device9").hide();$("#device10").hide(); $("#SubmitSecondPart").hide(); $("#alertquantity").show();
    if ($("#devicequantity").val() == 1) {$("#alertquantity").hide(); $("#device1").show(); $("#SubmitSecondPart").show();
    }
    else if ($("#devicequantity").val() == 2) {$("#alertquantity").hide(); $("#device1").show(); $("#device2").show(); $("#SubmitSecondPart").show();
    }
    else if ($("#devicequantity").val() == 3) {$("#alertquantity").hide(); $("#device1").show(); $("#device2").show(); $("#device3").show(); $("#SubmitSecondPart").show();
    }
});
</script>
</script>
```

**userinterface.py**

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      getInputsSettings()
      getInputsLicenses()
   return render_template('printerlabel.html', devicequantity=devicequantity)

@app.route("/getdevicequantity")
def getdevicequantity():
   return jsonify({'devicequantity' : devicequantity})

def runuserinterface():
   app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run()
```

**central.py**

```
devicequantity = 10
if __name__ == "__main__":
    userinterface.devicequantity=devicequantity
    userinterface.runuserinterface()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your AJAX success callback function has a response parameter that you need to use.

It supposed to look like this:

```js
success: function(response){
    $("#devicequantity").html(response.devicequantity);
}
```

For debugging purpose you can try

```js
success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
}
```

Comment: If it does not work you might need to parse JSON. `.html(JSON.parse(response). devicequantity)`

Comment: hey there! Tried applying your suggestion but it still wouldn't work. The devicequantity wouldn't update, and it cannot get $("#devicequantity").val()... thanks so much for answering so quickly tho!

Comment: Try to console log `response` and you will see if it actually returns a value or you have other problems

Comment: The console says success, but the devicequantity on the webapp still doesn't get updated when a new value in central.py is saved. 
Does this maybe have to do with the fact that I assigned the value for userinterface.devicequantity from central.devicequantity?

Comment: I would be more helpful if you provide a screenshot of that response

Comment: I just added a screenshot of the console. Thank you so much again

Comment: When I said to log response I meant it. You need to log response variable. Let me update my answer and try that one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216063/discussion-between-harry-and-hellieteres).